# Can this simpler case of the 2d maximum submatrix problem be solved more quickly?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an n by m matrix of integers, there is a well known problem of finding the submatrix with maximum sum. This can be solved with a 2d version of [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). An explanation of an O(nm^2) time algorithm for the 2D version which is based on Kadane's algorithm can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-submatrix/).

I am interested in a simpler version where only submatrices that include the top left cell of the matrix are considered. Can this version be solved faster in O(nm) time? If so, how can you do it? I  would also like to see what the optimal submatrix is, not just its sum.

Comment: Please post your code, maybe we can make it quicker... also, how big is the matrix, datatype, etc...

Comment: As a lower bound, I don't think it can be done faster than O(nm). Here is my argument: the algorithm must read each cell of the matrix at least once, which takes O(nm) time.

Comment: @NickODell Sorry I meant, can it be solved in O(nm) time, which is faster than the O(nm^2) time solution for the more general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in O(nm), for example by accumulating over the rows and then accumulating over the columns. That gives you all the sums, so just take the max.

Example implementation to find the max sum:

```
from itertools import accumulate

max(max(accumulate(c))
    for c in zip(*map(accumulate, A)))
```

And to also find the bottom-right corner indexes of the max sum submatrix:

```
max(
    (sum, i, j)
    for j, column in enumerate(zip(*map(accumulate, A)))
    for i, sum in enumerate(accumulate(column))
)
```

A few variations and testing (`fast4` returns the indexes of the bottom-right cell of the max sum submatrix instead of the sum, and `fast5` to `fast7` return sum and indexes):

```py
import random
from itertools import accumulate, chain, count, repeat

def sum_until(A, i, j):
    return sum(sum(row[:j+1]) for row in A[:i+1])

def naive(A):
    return max(
        sum(sum(row[:width]) for row in A[:height])
        for height in range(len(A) + 1)
        for width in range(len(A[0]) + 1)
    )

def fast1(A):
    return max(max(accumulate(c)) for c in zip(*map(accumulate, A)))

def fast2(A):
    return max(map(max, map(accumulate, zip(*map(accumulate, A)))))

def fast3(A):
    return max(chain(*map(accumulate, zip(*map(accumulate, A)))))

def fast4(A):
    sums = *chain(*map(accumulate, zip(*map(accumulate, A)))),
    return divmod(sums.index(max(sums)), len(A))[::-1]

def fast5(A):
    return max(
        max(zip(accumulate(c), count(), repeat(j)))
        for j, *c in zip(count(), *map(accumulate, A))
    )

def fast6(A):
    return max(
        (sum, i, j)
        for j, column in enumerate(zip(*map(accumulate, A)))
        for i, sum in enumerate(accumulate(column))
    )

def fast7(A):
    return max(map(max,
        map(zip,
            map(accumulate, zip(*map(accumulate, A))),
            map(count, repeat(0)),
            map(repeat, count())
        )
    ))

random.seed(4)
for _ in range(8):
    A = [random.choices(range(-15, 16), k=23) for _ in range(42)]
    print(
        {naive(A), fast1(A), fast2(A), fast3(A), sum_until(A, *fast4(A))},
        {fast5(A), fast6(A), fast7(A)}
    )
```

Output for eight test cases, showing that all solutions find the same max sum ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVTbTuMwEH3al3zFPNrFRaQUFkXiId8RVShKHOIS25HjwO4ivmSFxAt8FF-zdpyL04aKrRRVtmeOz_GZmb8f9W9dSvH29t7qYn3z-eOV8VoqDSoVueRBoSQHpqnSUlYN9IdplrW8rVJNCWRlyoT5k63QBBStaaqDIKcFNC2_M5usQjEBRmCPowDMT1HdKmGPkf2UfEqi_Vm4w1BIBWYJTECcRMzuOSiRskeK4jkAT3-hbm1_M7QnluvyCK-k7L7UBnLIscdu00YYxfcUVVSYe-AMwnlcB3kQllzsvMieapE2Olyiar_p4VCGHb_Mgv5hNVrxtEb-y8YYe5ibZcza4hI4zP0S0Ie8XILs_DzO_RbgdgQ0VjRwC6v_RiM-n5w9cplbX5tzJnLqHtEuTSA4q3ASRetwN5G4OlkndmFvnznRly_CQwGjvdXl-78nRsxg1Ri9pOGwGK5P8rFq-u44vC-TVcuFvZOKllNluX5dKH6ygTOw80xfcAd8zPTnqRLzXrC2NKaNYfNbBh-nzSYHulgKcWejS5PYXoLR4ObVeUNpjrY4sK9wN7XrTa8rNjWZ9KFZKVlGG-Qi1uEVgfDaePpwu7l0rekBbDd41yHUihkKI4HnYTKRsfHJ2K5k7DIyH4aroVnwyyT2eSheMpYNGW15cULdlO6H9TC0_wE)):

```
{311} {(311, 23, 22)}
{429} {(429, 33, 21)}
{252} {(252, 28, 3)}
{262} {(262, 39, 13)}
{196} {(196, 41, 22)}
{513} {(513, 39, 14)}
{252} {(252, 41, 4)}
{365} {(365, 16, 14)}
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer. How can you also find out what the optimal submatrix is?

Comment: @Simd Its bottom right cell is where the max sum occurs.

Comment: Can the bottom right cell be extracted from any of your fast solutions?

Comment: @Simd You can integrate tracking of the indexes. I see you changed the question *again* to include that, which is discouraging. How many more changes?

Comment: To be fair, the question always talked about finding the sub matrix. “ Given an n by m matrix of integers, there is a well known problem of finding the submatrix with maximum sum. ”

Comment: @Simd Right, but so does the page that you linked to for the implementation of the harder problem (*"find the maximum sum sub-matrix"*), and that doesn't show the submatrix, either, only its sum. Both in its example and in its solutions. You provided no example or implementation of your own, so I went with the ones you linked to. Code-wise, the simplest might be to store the `chain(...)` of my third variant in a list, find the maximum value, then find its index, and `divmod` it by n.

Comment: @Simd I forgot that I transposed, but `fast4` is now a working version of that idea.

Comment: (Somewhat amusingly, "divmod by n" was correct, as I was thinking in the standard naming scheme ("m by n matrix"), not in your question's ("n by m matrix").)

Comment: @Simd Added some more, `fast6` is now my favorite for getting sum and bottom-right corner, and `fast7` is a fun one avoiding `for` (a hobby of mine).

Answer (score 2):

[Integral image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_image), pseudocode:

```py
ii = [...] # integral image; set first row/column as a cumulative sums of the original image

max_sum = -inf

for row in range(1, nrows):
    for column in range(1, ncolumns):
        ii[row][column] = ii[row-1][column] + ii[row][column-1] - ii[row-1][column-1]
        max_sum = max(max_sum, ii[row][column])
```

Overall, 4 operations per cell = O(mn)